Email Verification in laravel while working with multi tenant
So I have the back end in Laravel and applied Laravel for tenancy into it. the front end is my nuxt. whenever I register, I want it should send an email for email verification which is working perfectly fine !! so this is my register method
public function register(Request $request) {
        $user = [];

        $tenant = Tenant::create(['name' => $request->first_name . 'Team']);
        $tenant->run(function () use ($request){
            Artisan::call('db:seed', ['--class' => 'DatabaseSeeder']);
            $user = User::create([
                'first_name' => $request->first_name,
                'last_name' => $request->last_name,
                'email' => $request->email,
                'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
                'phone_number' => $request->phone_number,
               // 'verification_token' => Str::random(60),
            ]);
            //return $user;
            event(new Registered($user));
        });

       
        $tenant->domains()->create([
            'domain' => $request->domain_name,
        ]); 
       // $tenant->users()->attach($user->id);
    
       return response()->json(['message' => 'Successfully created - Check your email to verify!']);
    }

whenever I click on Verify Email address button in my email, it navigates to http://domain1.localhost:8000/email/verify/2/2022b4a0a511f6ec4652cb178731383316eedf89?expires=1715858060&signature=d6fbdc6d1f5eeae04850be5215287f90f38601fdcc7dd87fd120b49d32a5890f because my server is running on domain1.localhost:8000
So my first link to send notice of email is working perfectly fine ---
Route::middleware([
    'web',
    InitializeTenancyByDomain::class,
    PreventAccessFromCentralDomains::class,
])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/email/verify', function () {
        return view('auth.verify-email');
    })->name('verification.notice');
    
    /* Route::get('/email/verify/{id}/{hash}', function (EmailVerificationRequest $request) {
        $request->fulfill();
     
        return redirect('/home');
    })->name('verification.verify'); */

    Route::get('/email/verify/{id}/{hash}', [VerifyEmailController::class, '__invoke'])
    ->middleware(['signed', 'throttle:6,1'])
    ->name('verification.verify');
   // Route::get('/verification/{token}', [AuthController::class, 'verify_email']);

But then at the click of the verify button, it required to sign and auth two middleware as per documentation which I removed in the above link. I don't want it should be logged in, so I have created my own controller named VerifyEmailController. which has the following code -
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Verified;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException;
use Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\VerifyEmailResponse;

class VerifyEmailController extends Controller
{
    public function __invoke(Request $request)
    {
        $user = User::findOrFail($request->route('id'));
        auth()->login($user);

        if (! hash_equals(sha1($user->getEmailForVerification()), (string) $request->route('hash'))) {
            throw new AuthorizationException;
        }

        if ($user->hasVerifiedEmail()) {
            return app(VerifyEmailResponse::class);
        }

        if ($user->markEmailAsVerified()) {
            event(new Verified($user));
        }

        return app(VerifyEmailResponse::class);
    }
}

    

still, whenever I execute, an email is being sent, and then on the click of the verify button, it displays

Method Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard::login does not exist.

In USER Modal, I have done this -
class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail{
   use Notifiable;


Features::emailVerification(), is listed. Please help me verify the email and set the verified column in the database as per tenant.Below are my routes for api.php -
Route::post('/login', [AuthController::class, 'login']);
Route::post('/register', [AuthController::class, 'register']);

Route::get('/csrf', [CsrfCookieController::class, 'get'])->name('csrf');



Route::middleware([
    'api',
    InitializeTenancyByDomain::class,
    PreventAccessFromCentralDomains::class,
])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
        $user = $request->user();
    
        if ($user->hasRole('Admin')) {
            $user['scope'] = array('Admin');
        }
        if ($user->hasRole('Driver')) {
            $user['scope'] = array('Driver');
        }
        if ($user->hasRole('Employee')) {
            $user['scope'] = array('Employee');
        }

        $data = [
            'user' => $user
        ];
        return $data;
    });
});

Route::prefix('admin')->middleware([
    'api',
    InitializeTenancyByDomain::class,
    PreventAccessFromCentralDomains::class,
])->group(function () {
    
    /**
     * Bookings
     */
    //Route::resource('/tenants', TenantController::class);
    Route::get('/email/verify/{id}/{hash}', [VerifyEmailController::class, '__invoke'])
    ->middleware(['signed', 'throttle:6,1'])
    ->name('verification.verify');
    Route::post('/bookings/change-recall-status', [BookingController::class, 'change_recall_status']);
}); 
Route::prefix('driver')->middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/trips/recall', [TripController::class , 'get_recall_rides']);
}); 

In my auth - i have
 'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'sanctum',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],


'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'sanctum' => [
        'driver' => 'sanctum',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],


'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],


This is unfortunately not a Nuxt-related question.
